I need help validating the calculation of a adjusted mortality rate
I'm working with a set of data of hemodialysis patients and need to analyse mortality rate. It is a retrospective cohort of 11,000 pts with 6 months of follow up. I used a Poisson model to calculate the crude rate. I want to adjust it for 4 other covariates (age, sex, cause, and time in dialysis).
I fitted a Poisson model with all the adjustment covariates and then used then with the IRR (original crude rate) from the unadjusted model. To calculate the adjusted mortality rate I used the crude rate times the product of the weighted average of each covariate. The results roughly make sense. I'm not sure if I'm doing the whole thing correctly and if I should use the crude rate from the unadjusted model (as I did) or the cons. from the adjusted model.
